# Script .bat to move files

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, cmd

I'm writing a batch script with `cmd.exe` and `powerShell.exe` commands, to copy a `.txt file`, (which is created by a third-party software), in its installation folder, to another place.

The main problem is that when I run the `.bat` file and it copies the file, the resulting copy hasn't the same content, it adulters the original content.

Here follows the code:

```bash
@echo off
set "origin_folder=C:\Program Files (x86)\PaperCut Print Logger\logs\"
set "destiny_folder=L:"

rem takes the most recent file
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('powershell -Command "& {Get-ChildItem '%origin_folder%' | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1}"') do (
    set "recent_file=%%I"
)

if not defined recent_file (
    echo No file found
    exit /b 1
)

rem Gets computer name
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('hostname') do set "computer_name=%%a"

rem Gets date
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/" %%a in ('echo %date%') do (
    set "month=%%b"
    set "day=%%a"
)

rem Assembly file's name
set "new_name=%computer_name%_%day%-%month%.txt"

rem Moves the most recent file to the destiny folder
move "%recent_file%" "%destiny_folder%"

echo Successfully moved: %recent_file% -> %destiny_folder%\%new_name%
```

The content was expected to be a number, but I get ...

```
Successfully moved: %recent_file% -> %destiny_folder%
```

... in its content (%% filled). I tried exclude this line, but the code does nothing instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
set "origin_folder=C:\Program Files (x86)\PaperCut Print Logger\logs\"
set "destiny_folder=L:"
set "origin_folder=U:\Program Files (x86)\PaperCut Print Logger\logs"
set "destiny_folder=U:"

rem takes the most recent file
rem for /f "delims=" %%I in ('powershell -Command "& {Get-ChildItem '%origin_folder%' | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1}"') do (
for /f "tokens=5" %%I in ('powershell -Command "& {Get-ChildItem '%origin_folder%' | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1}"') do (
    set "recent_file=%%I"
)

if not defined recent_file (
    echo No file found
    exit /b 1
)

rem Gets computer name
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('hostname') do set "computer_name=%%a"

rem Gets date
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/" %%a in ('echo %date%') do (
    set "month=%%b"
    set "day=%%a"
)

rem Assembly file's name
set "new_name=%computer_name%_%day%-%month%.txt"

rem Moves the most recent file to the destiny folder
ECHO move "%origin_folder%\%recent_file%" "%destiny_folder%\%new_name%"
move "%origin_folder%\%recent_file%" "%destiny_folder%\%new_name%"

echo Successfully moved: %recent_file% -^> %destiny_folder%\%new_name%
GOTO :EOF
```

Issues:

The `setlocal` line is missing. Including it will mean that when the batch ends, any variations made to the environment will be discarded. This means executing several batch programs within the same session does not accumulate changes.

[style] IMHO, it is easier to **not** include trailing `\` in values assigned to variables but to add them as required.

I changed the values assigned to suit my system.

The value assigned to `%%I` and hence `recent_file` was `-a----        07/02/2024     22:35         205826 later.txt` for me (file detected was `later.txt` in my setup) - and appeared to be unterminated.

Therefore, I changed `delims=` to `tokens=5` to use the fifth token (attribute date time size **filename**) with the default delimiters. Note that if the filename includes spaces, etc. this will need to be adjusted.

I `echo`ed a reconstructed `move` command.

The `move` command needed the *origin_folder* to be included, else the command would attempt to move the file from the **current directory**.

Similarly, the destination seemed illogical, so I altered the destination specification to what appears to be more logical.

and finally, `>` is a special character meaning `redirect stdout` (usually console output) and requires to be "escaped" by a caret (`^`) to disable its special meaning.

Answer (score 0):

How about doing this all with PowerShell? When you are confident that the file will be moved correctly, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Move-Item` command.

```
$OriginFolder = "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\PaperCut Print Logger\logs"
$DestinyFolder = 'L:'
$FileToCopy = Get-ChildItem -Path $OriginFolder | Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
$ComputerName = $Env:COMPUTERNAME
$DateMark = Get-Date -Format 'ddMM'
$DestinationFile = "$ComputerName$DateMark.txt"
Move-Item -Path $FileToCopy.FullName `
    -Destination (Join-Path -Path $DestinyFolder -ChildPath $DestinationFile") -WhatIf
```

If you -must- use a .bat file:

```
@pwsh -NoProfile -NoLogo -File 'Move-PcLogFile.ps1'
```